# Error: ENOENT, open favicon.ico

Tags: node.js, express

I am newbie with node and express

I created a express sample project by first writing

```
express test1
```

then i did

```
npm install
```

For testing the application i am doing node app.js, but i am getting this error

> Error: ENOENT, open
>   '/home/test1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/static-favicon/../public/favicon.ico'

I did some googling and i am not sure the solution, this is the demo app from express and should work, i have tired this last week and it was working.

Any insights would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked `public/favicon.ico` file exists?

Comment: yes the file exists but the location is /home/test1/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/static-favico/favicon.ico

Comment: Is this the latest version of express (3)?

Comment: yes express version 3.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append this line into the initialization section of your app.js:

```
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
```

I assume that app.js is in the project directory and favicon file is at public/favicon.ico also relative to the project folder.